# How to switch label with tab key Tkinter?

Tags: python, tabs, tkinter, label

I don't know how to enable this : I want to switch from a label to another with the Tab key in my window which contains several Labels.

I searched in the documentation but I found nothing.

Thank you.

Comment: Ok sorry for my english, I mean I have several fields that must be filled and I want to switch from one to another with the Tab key, like in a normal request form.

Answer (score 0):

By default, pressing tab will move you from widget to widget in the order that they are created -- you don't have to do anything to get this behavior (except for Text widgets, where by default a tab will insert a tab). If you need to change the order you have to change the stacking order using the [lift](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.lift-method) and [lower](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.lower-method) methods of a widget.